# Best way to reload component in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

In my application I have a list of different "questions" each question refers to one of two components controlled by a variable `QuestionIndex` that basically takes the current object in the list.

So I have `Component A`, which has a form inside of it with two Radio buttons:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <label>
    <span class="inlineBlock">
      <input type="radio" value="Ja" formControlName="response" class="radioInput">
      <span class="labelSpan">Ja</span>
    </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span class="inlineBlock">
    <input type="radio" value="Nej" formControlName="response" class="radioInput">
    <span class="labelSpan">Nej</span>
    </span>
  </label>

</form>
```

I fill out the form and increase the `QuestionIndex`.

Then the form inside of that component is not reloaded but already filled out.

How can I ensure that the `component` is completely reloaded?

I have tried with `ngOnChanges` but this won't really work because there are so many values I need to reset and each reset fires the `ngOnChanges` again.

**How it's used**

Below is how the component is used when the index is increased the `currentQuestion` object is changed and therefore the `component` is loaded

```
<app-radio-question [text]="currentQuestion.text"
                    *ngIf="currentQuestion.type == 'RadioQuestion' && !showEndQuestion"
                    [title]="currentQuestion.title" [NoOptionText]="currentQuestion.noOption"
                    [YesOptionText]="currentQuestion.yesOption"
                    [cacheData]="cacheData"
                    (formChangedEvent)="OnQuestionResponse($event)"></app-radio-question>
```

However this component is changed but not updated this means that if I change a value inside of it I get the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.

Comment: For better understanding post the part of your HTML where `QuestionIndex` is used

Answer (score 0):

This input is not bound to any variable at all.
You should consider doing that and just reset that specific variable

HTML

```
    <input [(ngModel)]="inputVariableName" (change)="onChangeFunc()" value="true" formControlName="response" class="radioInput"/>
```

TS

```
inputVariableName = false; // initial

onChangeFunc() {
    inputVariableName = false; //set it to initial again
}
```

But you have to import FormsModule for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is not really "about" the radio buttons but more about when the data of a component changes to reload it

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: This answer explains that you don't need to reload the component to reset the form, by showing how to reset the form without reloading it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you used some kind of framework for radio buttons. I use Angular Material and the radio buttons is grouped like this:

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

A full example can be find here [Radio Button Angular Material](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mxjemkvdbgl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-overview-example.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is not really "about" the radio buttons but more about when the data of a component changes to reload it